# dynamically changing headers in flex datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, variables, datagrid, header

I currently have a datagrid with some hard coded values for the headers however I need one of the headers to change based on a paramater from a query. e.g the result of the query may be "result1". In this case I need the header of the column to be "result1". 
I have tried running a query and assigning the result to a variable but have been unable to get the header to update each time the grid does. Is it possible to take this approach or is there another way?
I am quite new to this

Comment: Just use data binding on [GridColumn.headerText](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html#headerText)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like RIAStar said, you can always use

```
<mx:DataGridColumn hederText="{yourResult}" id="dgCol"/>
```

Just in case if you cannot use binding, you can also set

```
dgCol.headerText = yourResult;
```

One more thing, if you want a complete repaint of the grid, you can do

```
yourGrid.dataProvider.refresh();
```

or

```
yourGrid.invalidateList();
```